# Rails: howto access Devise's current user outside controllers with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I do not want to violate MVC, I'd like to achive the following: I'm rolling my own authorization lib with ActiveAdmin. Now I'd like to disable all ActiveAdmin actions that can not be accessed by the current user. That looks like so:

```
visible_actions = [:index, :show, :new].reject{|action| !AdminUser.first.can_access?("admin/privileges", action.to_s) }

ActiveAdmin.register Privilege do
  actions *visible_actions
  ... <other stuff>
end
```

But instead of AdminUser.first I'd like to access the current user. Devise's authentication process has already finished when my piece of code is parsed. So the current_user should be known already. But I do not find a way to access the current_user in a clean way.

Is there any way? Thx in advance. Felix